# Two Rails servers with the same Time.zone, same server timezone, but getting different results from Date.to_time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am running Rails on two machines, but getting different results from `to_time` method. I only checked the system timezone and `Time.zone` configuration, am I missing anything? Thanks

**Server 1**

```
user@Server1:/var/www/app$ date
Wed Oct 23 23:56:35 MDT 2013
user@Server1:/var/www/app$ cat /etc/timezone
America/Denver

user@Server1:/var/www/app$ bundle exec rails c production
irb(main):011:0> Time.zone
=> (GMT+00:00) UTC
irb(main):012:0> Date.parse("10/24/2013").to_time
=> 2013-10-24 00:00:00 +0000
```

**Server 2**

```
user@Server2:/var/www/app$ date
Thu Oct 24 00:03:28 MDT 2013
user@Server2:/var/www/app$ cat /etc/timezone
America/Denver

user@Server2:/var/www/app$ bundle exec rails c production
irb(main):002:0> Time.zone
=> (GMT+00:00) UTC
irb(main):003:0> Date.parse("10/24/2013").to_time
=> 2013-10-24 00:00:00 -0600
```

Comment: Could you do a `rails c` and see if `ENV['TZ']` returns something different?

Comment: @PeterHuene Yes they have different `ENV['TZ']`! Server1 has `"UTC"` but Server2 has `nil`. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Time#local_time` (called by ActiveSupport in the implementation of Date#to_time) respects the `TZ` environment variable for which timezone should be used for the "local" time.

Ensure that the environment is the same between the two servers.